# How does Spring manages Date parameter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, date

I have an endpoint that accepts Date parameter. Format is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ. My current timezone is set to SGT.

If I invoke the endpoint with 2019-08-13T00:00:00Z, spring converts the value to Tue Aug 13 08:00:00 SGT 2019. When I invoke with 2019-08-13T00:00:00+08:00, this is converted to Tue Aug 13 00:00:00 SGT 2019.

Any idea on how Spring handle this value? Also, if there is a manual (programtically) way I can achieve the same result. See below for my endpoint.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void exportToS3(@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    @RequestParam(value = "exportDate") Date exportDate) {

    controller.exportTransactions(exportDate);
}
```

Comment: Use `java.time.ZonedDateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

```
String timeStamp = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss")
                   .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()))
                   .replace("_", "T");
```

where `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` is your **time variable**.

Comment: You have missed something very important.  The date I passed via postman is 2019-08-13T00:00:00Z and by the time it gets to the java code, it is changed to Tue Aug 13 08:00:00 SGT 2019. Time is converted from 00:00:00 to 08:00:00. Which is I am struggling.

Answer (score 0):

‘Z’ represent the date is in UTC zone and your server is running on SGT or it convert it to SGT. In second case ‘+8:00’ represent the zone is SGT or there is no change in date.

For consistency you should use ZonedDateTime instead of Date. ZonedDateTime keeps the date in a same zone and convert accordingly.